# Using Product rule to take derivative

Tags: derivatives, signal-processing

I'm trying to take the derivative of:
$$\frac{-1}{6}(e^{-3t}-1) u(t)$$

The $u(t)$ is the step response. So the answer I get is by just doing product rule:
$$\frac{1}{2}e^{-3t}u(t)-\frac{1}{6}e^{-3t}\delta(t)$$ but wolfram gets a different [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/dt%20%28-1/6%29%28e%5E%28-3t%29-1%29heaviside%28t%29).

Why does:
$-\frac{1}{6}e^{-3t}\delta(t)$ goes to $0$?

Comment: Wolfram takes classical derivatives where they exist (and only those).  The heaviside function is not differentiable at zero in the classical sense, so Wolfram doesn't bother taking the derivative there.  What you are taking is a weak derivative, and I don't think Wolfram is capable of doing those.

Comment: @Chris so then is my answer perfectly correct?

Comment: The product rule still holds for distributions (which is what the delta function really is), so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Because "it has a bug"?

In my *MMA* (v8.0,Linux-x64),

```
 D[-(1/6) (E^(-3 t) - 1) HeavisideTheta[t], t]
```

outputs

```
 -(1/6) (-1 + E^(-3 t)) DiracDelta[t] 
                          + 1/2 E^(-3 t) HeavisideTheta[t]
```